# If I set a variable using `CreateObject()`, do I need to clean it up by setting it to `Nothing` after use?

Tags: vbscript, resource-cleanup

If I set a variable using `CreateObject()`, do I need to clean it up by setting it to `Nothing` after use?

```
Dim foo
Set foo = CreateObject("SomeAssembly")
foo Bar
Set foo = Nothing
```

I just found [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2004/04/28/122259.aspx) by [Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert):

> The script engine will automatically clear those variables when they go out of scope, so clearing them the statement before they go out of scope seems to be pointless.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

> If I set a variable using CreateObject(), do I need to clean it up by setting it to Nothing after use?

Typically you do not, but it has become lore in the VB community that you do. If you are a supersitious person, it doesn't *hurt* to ward off the evil eye by setting variables to `Nothing` when you are done with them, but it rarely helps anything either.

The rare cases where you do need to set a variable to `Nothing` are those cases where:

- you have created a circular reference that the garbage collector is unable to clean up
- the object is expensive but the variable is long-lived, so you want it to be cleaned up early
- the object implementation requires a particular shutdown order that must be maintained
- and so on.

If I'm not in one of those cases, I don't set variables to `Nothing`. I've never had a problem with that.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, most circular references are easy to clean up. The problem is caused when you have a circular reference with COM objects (which aren't GCed) in the way.

Comment: what about calling quit()?  Do you have to call application.quit() or xlApp.quit()?  It seems like there is an extra excel.exe process in my task manager if I do not call quit().

Answer (score 16):

I rarely do this:-

```
Set foo = Nothing
```

Here is why...

Consider:-

```
Function DoStuff()
    Dim foo : Set foo = CreateObject("lib.thing")
    ''# Code that uses foo
    Set foo = Nothing
End Function
```

Since `foo` is about to pass out of scope anyway assigning `Nothing` to `foo` is superfluous so I don't bother.

Consider:-

```
Function DoStuff()
    Dim foo : Set foo = CreateObject("lib.thing")
    ''# Code that uses foo
    Set foo = Nothing
    ''# Loads more code that doesn't use foo
End Function
```

Now this is a case where assigning `Nothing` makes sense since otherwise it's held for potentially a lot longer than is necessary.  **However** in such cases the code is a candidate for refactoring.  The fact that the function continues to do quite a lot more stuff not needing `foo` indicates that the `foo`-using chunk of code actually belongs in its own function:-

```
Function DoStuff()
    ''# Code that calls FooUsage
    ''# Loads more code that doesn't use foo
End Function

Function FooUsage(someParams)
    Dim foo : Set foo = CreateObject("lib.thing")
    ''# Code that uses foo
    FooUsage = someResult
End Function
```

There are occasions where assigning to `Nothing` for memory release purposes is advisable but I tend to do it in special cases.  In normal code I find it's rarely necessary.

Perhaps one of the drivers behind the "Always set to nothing" camp is that many VBScripters write sequential scripts that are not factored well into `Function` and `Sub` procedures.

Comment: _... many VBScripters write sequential scripts that are not factored well into Function and Sub procedures._ – That it is! Now I know why it is always hard to work in big old VBScript projects.

Answer (score 1):

If your variable is a module or global variable (declared near the top of your module, outside any procedure) then the variable may not go out of scope automatically at the end of your script.  That might cause a problem in some situations so you might consider setting the variable to nothing (or it's default if it's not a object variable).